# How do you call a location inside of a list which is a string?

Tags: python, list

I have been working on a maze game. I've first decided to make a mini tutorial level. The game development has just started, and right now I'm trying to make it move upwards. I am trying to change the PlayerAre variable but it's not working.

I have tried to put inside of a list and outside of a list.

```
maze = ["o","*","*","*","*","*",".",#row one is over
        ".",".",".",".",".","*","*",#Row two is over
        "*","*","*","*",".","*",".",#Row three is over
        ".",".",".","*",".","*",".",#Row four is over
        ".",".",".","*",".","*",".",#Row five is over
        ".",".",".","*",".","*",".",#Row Six is over
        ".",".",".","*",".","@"]

mazeOne = maze[0:6]
mazeTwo = maze[7:13]
mazeThree = maze[14:20]
mazeFour = maze[21:27]
mazeFive = maze[28:34]
mazeSix = maze[35:41]
mazeSeven = maze[42:48]
playerAre = maze[47]

for a,b,c,d,e,f,g in zip (mazeOne, mazeTwo, mazeThree, mazeFour, 
mazeFive, mazeSix, mazeSeven):
    print (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

keypress = str(input("""W, A, S, D: """))
if keypress == 'w' or keypress == 'W':
    playerAre = '.'
    playerAre = playerAre + 7
```

Comment: How does one add seven to a period?  Is that some sort of ASCII code thing?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, it just gives a `TypeError`.

Comment: You are changing it to '.' with the first reassignment, but the purpose of your next `playerAre` assignment is unclear..

Comment: What are you trying to change `playerAre` to? Also, are you trying to add the new element to your `maze` list? Or are you trying to change the element from `maze`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two immediate problems here.

- You've confused the *contents* of `maze` (the * . @ characters you use to display the maze) with the *index* (integers 0-48).
- You seem to be trying to move the player upward by *adding* 7 to the location.  Note that this would give you a location of 54, which is outside of the maze.  I think you want to subtract.

Try this for a quick fix:

```
if keypress.lower() == 'w':
    maze[playerAre] = '.'
    playerAre = playerAre - 7
```

I strongly recommend that you look at several of the *many* maze examples on line.  See how they handle moves more "naturally", starting with a 2D organization of the maze layout.